# convert bwconncomp method of matlab to c#

Tags: c#, matlab, converters

i need to convert BwConnComp method of matlab to c#,

can anybody help me to get this method source code or offer an algorithm to convert this method to c# language?

i need to get connected component of 3d image(such as a cube)